# Software to help in log analysis?

Tags: analysis, logging

Hey guys, I have a quick question.

Does anyone know of any software that can help with understanding client-server logs?

I have 3 huge logs of 1 server & 2 clients that are time stamped, but only if I could arrange all 3 of them in a UI side by side in a chronological order, it would be so easy for me to understand them.

Thanks for any tips on such a software. (Or maybe some ideas to help me with this.)3[image]

Edit: the mockup image has blue line partitions to separate out time in milliseconds. That is just for visualization.

Comment: While I can see a legitimate programming context for this question, you haven't been specific about that, so I've voted to move to Server Fault where you are--in any case--likely to find more experts.

Comment: Update: I have attached an mockup drawing image file. Just for better understanding.

Comment: Update: I couldn't find anything even close to what I was looking for. I ended up making a small dirty program to output an intermix of logs into a tab-delimited log file (which I later opened in excel).

Comment: In future, I plan to make a generic utility for everyone to use. Not closing this question as of now, I will update here later.... Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what platform but [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) is something that can be useful. Here are some [samples](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html).

Comment: And [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html) is a blog posting about it from Jeff Atwood himself.

Answer (score 0):

[Google BigQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/bigquery/) is a helpful tool for analyzing massive datasets, including logs. It doesn't give you a UI, but it does provide a SQL-like language for making queries over the logs.

Comment: So, the latest version of BigQuery now provides a Browser based UI, as well as a very feature rich command line tool!