# Features rich DNS server software?

Tags: dns, statistics

I am looking for DNS server software with statistics like all unqie IPs connected past 24hrs, top domain queries and etc... 
Anyone know such software with free-license ?

Comment: This is not the correct place to ask this question. I do not believe *any* Stack Exchange site is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not done through DNS. This is done with server logs. If you want big data there are plenty of tools, google it. google is even one of the answers.

Possible duplicate of:
[Software to help in log analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020025/software-to-help-in-log-analysis)